# Working with Python Requests response raw file-like object (process pcap file without saving it to disk)

Tags: python, python-requests, scapy, dpkt

A pcap file is downloaded from url with the help of Python (2.7.9) Requests library:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://example.com/path/1.pcap',  stream=True)
```

According to documentation `response.raw` is a file-like object and my goal is to process the downloaded file without saving it to disk.

I first looked at `Scapy` and `Pyshark` libraries for `.pcap` file parsing but their functions (`rdpcap` and `FileCapture`) accept file path string as an argument. `pcap.Reader` from `dpkt` library accepts a file object. The first try `pcap=dpkt.pcap.Reader(resonse.raw)` gave an error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Name attribute was added:

```
setattr(response.raw,'name', 'test.pcap')
```

After that `pcap=dpkt.pcap.Reader(resonse.raw)` didn't give any errors but `pcap.readpkts()` failed with

```
io.UsupportedOperation: seek
```

And indeed `response.raw.seekable()` returns `False`.

I tried setting `response.raw.decode_content = True` but that didn't help.

Is there a solution for processing the object the way I'm trying? Maybe additional request parameters are required to get a seekable response object?

By the way, if response object is written to file (`shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw,file)`), `dpkt` succeeds in working with that file afterwards.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet that fails, @Andrey ?

Answer (score 1):

Support for StringIO objects was recently added to [dpkt](https://github.com/kbandla/dpkt). So, now you can create a StringIO object from your string and then pass the to pcap.Reader

To create a StringIO object from a string:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
data = StringIO("aaaaa..aa")
```

You can then do

```
import dpkt
from StringIO import StringIO
import requests

response = requests.get('http://example.com/path/1.pcap',  stream=True)
data = StringIO(response.raw)
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(data)
    for ts, buf in pcap:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        ...
```

Comment: You should mention that the way to do this is to `from StringIO import StringIO# (or cStringIO)` and then wrapping your string with `wrapped_string = StringIO("my string here")`

Comment: Kiran, thank you. I hope that this method will work but I haven't been able to test it yet. After upgrading DPKT it fails at `from test import pystone` with error `cannot import name pystone`. I installed `test` package from pip but it does not contain `pystone`. Haven't been able to resolve that yet (I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Andrey, pystone is part of Python 2.7. You do not have to install `test` from pip. At some point, you must have accidentally installed/copied a test.py or a test directory to your standard python lib. To check for this, do `import test` and then do `print test`. This will show you the location of test, which most likely overwrote the default `test` module.

Comment: Kiran, thank you, that solved the problem with `pystone`. But when passing `stringIO` object to `pcap.Reader` I get 'invalid tcpdump header' exception. When passing file object for the same pcap file everything is processed correctly.

Comment: @AndreyGrachev if that worked for you, can you mark it as the answer

Comment: @KiranBandla, actually it is not finally resolved for me - I still get `invalid tcpdump header` excpeption when using StringIO. I ended up copying the response to a file object before processing. I'll try to test one more time after upgrading `dpkt` version and will update later.

Comment: @KiranBandla, I upgraded `dpkt` to the latest version (1.9.0) and still got `invalid tcpdump header` when using `StringIO`.